# Best rails gem to populate associated model via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Say we have two models A and B, and that they have a belongs_to association such that A has many B's and B belongs to A.

I'm looking for a gem (a form gem?) that will simplify retrieving, via Ajax, all B objects that belong to a selected A object when selecting it from a form. The B object will be available to be selected using a checkbox.

Tried to find a solution on Railscasts (even on the pro) to no avail.

Comment: Why would you need a gem for that? You can do this with just rails. And some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

While ccvandermeer is accurate, and I could provide samples, you might want to look at [chosen-rails](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails) to see if it can help.  I haven't used it, but take a look.

Otherwise, it always helps to provide code and discuss what you've done to try to make it work so far.